# Compilar extensão PHP-CPP no Windows

Tags: mingw, php-cpp

Estou tentando desenvolver uma extensão PHP com PHP-CPP no Windows. Consegui compilar o .a e .so do PHP-CPP com MingW, porem, quando vou compilar a extensão ele não encontra o phpcpp.h.

Meu Arquivo Makefile:

```
NAME                    =   Teste
INI_DIR             =   /etc/php5/conf.d
EXTENSION_DIR           =   $(shell php-config --extension-dir)
EXTENSION           =   ${NAME}.so
INI                     =   ${NAME}.ini
COMPILER                =   g++
LINKER              =   g++
PHP_CONFIG          =   php-config
COMPILER_FLAGS      =   -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic -o
LINKER_FLAGS            =   -shared
LINKER_DEPENDENCIES =   -lphpcpp
RM                  =   rm -f
CP                  =   cp -f
MKDIR                   =   mkdir -p
SOURCES             =   $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS             =   $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
all:                    ${OBJECTS} ${EXTENSION}
${EXTENSION}:           ${OBJECTS}
                    ${LINKER} ${LINKER_FLAGS} -o $@ ${OBJECTS}         ${LINKER_DEPENDENCIES}
${OBJECTS}:
                    ${COMPILER} ${COMPILER_FLAGS} $@ ${@:%.o=%.cpp}
install:        
                    ${CP} ${EXTENSION} ${EXTENSION_DIR}
                    ${CP} ${INI} ${INI_DIR}

clean:
                    ${RM} ${EXTENSION} ${OBJECTS}
```

Estrutura de pastas:

main.cpp
Makefile
phpcpp.a
phpcpp.so

Adicionei os arquivos do PHP-CPP na pasta Include do MingW e o erro agora é esse:

```
C:\Users\PedroSoares\Desktop\PHP\build_folder>mingw32-make.exe all
g++ -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:1:0: warning: -fpic ignored for target (all code is position     independent) [enabled by default]
 #include <phpcpp.h>
 ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\phpcpp.h:34:0,
             from main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:17:21: error: variable     'Php::PHPCPP_EXPORT Php::IniValue' has initializer but incomplete type
 class PHPCPP_EXPORT IniValue
                 ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:19:1: error: expected primary-expression before 'public'
 public:
 ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:19:1: error: expected '}' before     'public'
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:19:1: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'public'
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:32:25: error: non-member function     'Php::operator int16_t()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     operator int16_t () const
                     ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:32:25: error: 'Php::operator int16_t()' must be a nonstatic member function
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:41:25: error: non-member function     'Php::operator int32_t()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     operator int32_t () const
                     ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:41:25: error: 'Php::operator int32_t()' must be a nonstatic member function
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:50:25: error: non-member function     'Php::operator int64_t()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     operator int64_t () const
                     ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:50:25: error: 'Php::operator int64_t()' must be a nonstatic member function
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:59:22: error: non-member function     'Php::operator bool()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     operator bool () const
                  ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:59:22: error: 'Php::operator bool()' must be a nonstatic member function
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:68:29: error: non-member function     'Php::operator std::string()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     operator std::string () const
                         ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:68:29: error: 'Php::operator     std::string()' must be a nonstatic member function
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:77:30: error: non-member function     'Php::operator const char*()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     operator const char * () const
                          ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:77:30: error: 'Php::operator const     char*()' must be a nonstatic member function
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:86:28: error: expected constructor,     destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
     operator double() const;
                        ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:98:28: error: non-member function     'int64_t Php::numericValue()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     int64_t numericValue() const;
                        ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:104:22: error: non-member function     'bool Php::boolValue()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     bool boolValue() const
                  ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:113:31: error: non-member function     'std::string Php::stringValue()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     std::string stringValue() const
                           ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h: In function 'std::string     Php::stringValue()':
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:115:37: error: 'rawValue' was not     declared in this scope
         return std::string(rawValue());
                                 ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h: At global scope:
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:122:28: error: non-member function     'const char* Php::rawValue()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     const char *rawValue() const;
                        ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:125:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'private'
 private:
 ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:147:1: error: 'PHPCPP_EXPORT' does not name a type
 PHPCPP_EXPORT std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const     IniValue &ini_val);
 ^
c:\mingw\include\phpcpp\inivalue.h:153:1: error: expected declaration     before '}' token
 }
 ^
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Como você está rodando o comando de compilação?

Comment: set PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin;
mingw32-make.exe

Comment: Uma coisa pedro `/etc/php5/conf.d` é um caminho linux e não windows. Você tem que compilar o php-cpp e jogar o .lib gerado na pasta do mingw (não me lembro qual pasta, acho que era a /libs) e tem que colocar os arquivos .h do php-cpp (não do teu projeto) em uma pasta que eu não me lembro (desculpe faz mais de um ano que não uso mingw :/)

Comment: a linha do /etc/php5/conf.d é só para a instalação, o problema é quando compila. Já adicionei as extensões na pasta /lib, mas não achei a outra pasta para por o source do php-cpp. Só com os arquivos na pasta /lib não faz diferença, o erro persiste.

Comment: Extensões você se refere aos `.lib`? No caso eu digo que na pasta libs/ tem que haver um arquivo chamado `phpcpp.lib` (acho que é algo assim), e tem outra pasta (o qual não lembro o nome) que tem que ficar o `phpcpp.h`. Vou tentar instalar o MingW e compilar o phpcpp (instalar) e depois tentar criar uma extensão.

Comment: a extensão na é .lib, .o e .so. Caso queira eu posso postar meu arquivo Makefile do PHP-CPP, pois tem que modificar muitas coisas para compilar no Windows.

Comment: Eu não estou entendendo bem, mas acho que você na verdade não entendeu o que eu disse, eu não estou falando da extensão que você esta criando e sim de como instalar o `phpcpp` junto ao mingw, o que quero dizer é que você deve compilar o "instalador" do phpcpp pelo mingw, então ele vai gerar um arquivo chamado `phpcpp.lib`, esse arquivo deve ir na pasta do mingw junto com o arquivo `phpcpp.h` (cada um na sua pasta respectiva) então ae sim você deve tentar compilar a "sua extensão". O que eu quero dizer, se ele acusa que falta o phpcpp.h é porque ele não esta na pasta do mingw.

Comment: Fiz o que disse, agora aparece o erro que esta ali em cima.

Comment: Pelo erro parece que você esquece algum outro arquivo que vem com o CPP. Você baixou o PHPCPP compativel com que compilador? Ou ele é cross-compiler?

Comment: Ele é cross-compiler.

Comment: Vou fazer assim, pode demorar alguns dias, mas vou instalar o Mingw e tentar compilar o phpcpp. Assim que conseguir te dou um feedback.

Comment: ok, muito obrigado.